# Pandas groupby all rows greater than _each_ value in column

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

I'm having trouble even wording the question, honestly, but it goes roughly like this: I need to perform a groupby that applies an aggregate function **not for all rows equal to each value** in the grouping column, but for all rows where the value of the grouping column is **greater than each value** in the column.

I'll be purposefully verbose, just in case. Let's say I have this dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Weight': [40, 50, 60, 70, 40, 60, 80, 100, 60, 40, 50, 70, 60],
    'Height': [150, 160, 170, 180, 190, 160, 150, 180, 170, 200, 210, 160, 180]
    })
```

On which I perform a simple groupby to find a mean value:

```
gb = df.groupby(['Weight'])['Height'].mean().reset_index()
gb
```

Which returns

```
   Weight  Height
0      40     180
1      50     185
2      60     170
3      70     170
4      80     150
5     100     180
```

But I need something like this (not real code obviously):

```
gb = df.groupby(["""a dynamic column or a mask of some sort that marks all rows where 'Weight' is greater than each of its unique values"""])['Height'].mean().reset_index()
gb
```

I can, of course, achieve the desired result by iterating over each unique value in the column like this:

```
res_list = []
for w in sorted(df['Weight'].unique().tolist()):
    res_list.append(df[df['Weight'] > w]['Height'].mean())
gb = pd.DataFrame({'Weight': sorted(df['Weight'].unique().tolist()), 'Height': res_list})
gb
```

Which will return exactly what I want:

```
   Weight  Height
0      40  172.00
1      50  168.75
2      60  167.50
3      70  165.00
4      80  180.00
5     100     NaN
```

But this method scales very poorly with number of unique values and number of columns that I need to perform this operation on.

I'm not married to groupby() specifically, but I have a feeling that there's a way to do it, and I just lack the googling skills to find the answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mean is just sum divided by count. Both sum and count can be accumulated in your case:

```
# Let's add another column for fun
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "Weight": [40, 50, 60, 70, 40, 60, 80, 100, 60, 40, 50, 70, 60],
        "Height": [150, 160, 170, 180, 190, 160, 150, 180, 170, 200, 210, 160, 180],
        "Age": np.random.randint(20, 100, 13),
    }
)

# for each Weight class, sum up the Height and Age, also count how many rows
# belonging to that class. The [::-1] reverses it so Weight are sorted from
# highest to lowest
tmp = (
    df.groupby("Weight")[["Height", "Age"]]
    .agg(["sum", "count"])
    .swaplevel(axis=1)[::-1]
)

# Take the sum of all rows with Weight higher than the current Weight
tmp = tmp.cumsum() - tmp

# The mean is just the sum divided by count
(tmp["sum"] / tmp["count"])[::-1]
```

Comment: Not exactly the solution I was hoping for, but it works!

Comment: Thanks to your answer, I rewrote the entire thing with a different approach and managed to make my calculations faster by a factor of ~7500. Your username is truly warranted!